# How do I get Edit Profile to not save with invalid date input on Joomla Community Builder

Tags: joomla, joomla-community-builder

On my volunteering website, users can edit their profile and enter a date in the future when they are available to volunteer. If they are already signed up for a volunteer opportunity, they shouldn't be able to change the dates they are available until they have fulfilled their assignment.  I am using CB Query Validation to check if they have a current assignment when they change their date.  The validation is working - that is, it is showing the error message when they change the date but shouldn't be changing it.  But it still allows them to save the profile edit with the new date.  Is there a way to disable the SAVE button if the error shows?

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Joomla questions should be asked on [Joomla Stack Exchange site](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question is now cross-posted. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/31527/12352